# How to get image dimensions on div load

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a div with a background image set. but its set to change its dimensions to fit the page. is there a way for me to get the height of the image that has been loaded and set the div height to that so that the next part of the page starts at the bottom of the image? So far I've been making the next part a static distance down, but then on some devices you can barely see the image.

EDIT: here is my CSS code:

```
.image-section {
    height: 700px;
    max-width: none;
    min-width: 40%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1a80a5;
    background-image: url('../images/CYAF3Wg.jpg');
    background-position: center 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it have to be a background image?

Comment: well thats just the way it is, Unless there is an eaiser way to display text over the top then I suppose is does.

Comment: @Dart2112 If you post a working code, or 2 images of 2 device size's, and show how you want it to look like, we can give you the best way, now it is just a wild guess.

Comment: I've added the CSS code so you can see what I'm working with. and I use JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `img` elements but display them similar to `background-image`, something like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bk6aou1L/) << check the console, and see images width and height.

You'll see that even though `img-0` and `img-1` width values are originally `500px` -*hence why in the img* `src="../500x350/`- but the output width has different values because these image `width` values are controlled with CSS `width:100%;` so javascript is giving us the exact "*current*" width.

Same for the images `height` values, although it is not set in CSS, but when we put `width:100%` without setting height the image will be respective while still maintaining the aspect ratio, yo ucan see that `img-0` height is less that `img-1` height because the first image has original image of `200px` while the second image `img-1` has `350px` height, again the output height is representing the actual and exact height on the screen no matter what the original height is.

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.container img');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  var image = imgs[i];
  console.log("img-" + i + " Width: " + image.offsetWidth);
  console.log("img-" + i + " Height: " + image.offsetHeight);
  console.log('--------');
}
```

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  color:#FF5;
}
.container .innerText{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.container img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="//placehold.it/500x200/009900/ffffff?text=IMG-0">
  <div class="innerText">
    this text is ABOVE the image..
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non corporis dicta quaerat rerum animi .
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="//placehold.it/500x350/000044/ffffff?text=IMG-1">
  <div class="innerText">
    this text is ABOVE the image Aslo..
    <br>Qui assumenda, itaque laboriosam culpa hic animi, eligendi voluptate similique quis placeat blanditiis, excepturi veritatis maiores ad rem!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will the image still adjust its size to fit the page though? this is the main problem with the page. for example ATM it looks fine on my laptop but on my desktop it is 2 pages before the image div ends and the rest of the page starts

Comment: yes, use the vertical window separator on the left side of the result window, to change the result window width and see how the image will still fill the parent container and you will always get updated and correct `width` and `height` values

Comment: check this image http://i.imgur.com/o4GtKn7.png to know what handler I am talking about, also notice different values of height and width in the console because I've already re-sized the result window couple times

Comment: I have no idea what half of that was, what is the vertical window separator and result window?
EDIT: sorry didn't see the new comment

Comment: thus it'll act just like background image but keep in mind that you need to wrap each div content in your page with an inner wrapper, just like `div.innerText` in my case

Comment: in http://jsfiddle.net you have 4 views, the left top for **html**, left bottom for **javascript**, right top for **css**, right bottom is the "**result**" view, so in order to see how the result behaves in responsive concerning, change the width of the result window by dragging it's left border -*separator between it and javascript window*, as you mouse over it you'll see how the mouse cursor changes, if you still have no idea, copy the above code to a local file and open it in your browser and do your tests

Comment: oh ok, I just use a diffeferent IDE so I was a little confused. thanks I'll igve it a shot

Comment: How would I drop the image down 60 pixels as it is hiding behind a navigation bar at the top

Comment: Either as in this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bk6aou1L/2/ , where you set the `.container` class to the navigation bar too, and other contents in another `.content`, it will work even if you don't add `.container` as long as the navigation bar is outside the `.container` div

Comment: The navbar requires its own class and putting in inside its own container div didnt work. I might just add white space to the image

Comment: Or if you only have one image treated as background, you can change the css `top` value to be more than your navigation bar height like in this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bk6aou1L/3/

Comment: if you already have a `.container` div in your, just change the `.container` div in my answer to something different, like `.contentWrapper` or use my answer as it is, and change your `container` class name to anotehr name like `wrapper`, check this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bk6aou1L/4/ I've changed my previously name `.container` div into `.contenWrapper`,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe load this image as `<img>` (with visibility hidden or display none) and after it loads You can check it's width/height (`.offsetWidth` / `.offsetHeight`).

Comment: I'd go this way.  Also checking the `.complete` property of the image as the load event wouldn't be fired if the image had already been loaded.

Comment: would I be able to tell it to load to the width of the page, at the moment I'm letting CSS deal with the laodign of it and the size. so can I do the same thing with an <img>?

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-size:100%;` to your CSS code where u are setting background image.

and if you want exact pixel then use this :

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = $('#myDiv').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
var bgImgWidth = img.width;
var bgImgHeight = img.height;
```

Comment: It's loading fine, and I want it to be addaptive to the page. I just need to find out the size it chooses to use

Comment: will that get the raw image size or the size of the image that has been changed to fit the screen?